# How to prepopulate save dialog box using JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am making an application that applies a filter to a picture. It asks the user where to save the new file immediately after selecting a source file. Is it possible to prepopulate the save dialog box with the source file name + _filtername?

Comment: If you look in the online Java documentation for JFileChooser http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setSelectedFile(java.io.File) you will see a function called setSelectedFile.  Looking at the online java docs is a wonderful way to find an answer (much quicker than using StackOverflow).  Searching on JFileChooser will also bring up other pages that may tell you the answer (although I didn't read them to find out).  If you have any question, please open a new question and post code and a more specific question.  You'll probably want to delete this one, though.

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a read through [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

You want to use [`JFileChooser#setSelectedFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setSelectedFile(java.io.File))

Comment: ..why not point to the [Java 8 docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setSelectedFile-java.io.File-)?

Answer (score 0):

This example for Open Dialog

```
        JFileChooser fd = new JFileChooser();
        fd.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(fd.getSelectedFile()==null&&pro_pic_text.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Choose your Profile Picrure","Warning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = fd.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            File ff = new File(fileName);
            String ffname = ff.getName();
            int aa = ffname.indexOf(".");
            fftype = ffname.substring(aa+1);
            if(fftype.equals("png") || fftype.equals("PNG") || fftype.equals("JPEG") || fftype.equals("jpeg") || fftype.equals("JPG") || fftype.equals("jpg"))
            {
                if(ff.length()<=51300)
                {
                    pro_pic_text.setText(fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"File size larger then 50kb not allowed","Warning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    pro_pic_text.setText("");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Choose JPEG, JPG or PNG File","Warning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                pro_pic_text.setText("");
            }
        }
```

Use this code my english is bad

this code have some validation like Supported file must have less then 50KB and only JPEG,jpeg,jpg,JPG,PNG,png file

I thing this is helping for you